# Decode JSON from URL query param

Tags: go

I am a newbie for golang proto. I need to decrypt the string that I was getting from the query param.

This is my string.

```
%7B%22predicates%22%3A%5B%7B%22key%22%3A%22name%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22IS_SUBSTRING%22%2C%22string_value%22%3A%22123%22%7D%2C%7B%22key%22%3A%22storage_state%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22NOT_EQUALS%22%2C%22string_value%22%3A%22STORAGESTATE_ARCHIVED%22%7D%5D%7D
```

I couldn't find how to decrypt this string.

Can anyone provide me an idea to decrypt this string using golang

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `url.PathUnescape(s)` from std lib (try it [online](https://play.golang.org/p/xyAPPf8fSH-)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    s := `%7B%22predicates%22%3A%5B%7B%22key%22%3A%22name%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22IS_SUBSTRING%22%2C%22string_value%22%3A%22123%22%7D%2C%7B%22key%22%3A%22storage_state%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22NOT_EQUALS%22%2C%22string_value%22%3A%22STORAGESTATE_ARCHIVED%22%7D%5D%7D`
    st, err := url.PathUnescape(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(st)
}
```

Output:

```
{"predicates":[{"key":"name","op":"IS_SUBSTRING","string_value":"123"},{"key":"storage_state","op":"NOT_EQUALS","string_value":"STORAGESTATE_ARCHIVED"}]}
```

You may [Unmarshal](https://play.golang.org/p/Ncmp4USN5O-):

```
    var m map[string]interface{}
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(st), &m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Or [decode](https://play.golang.org/p/Cd4mhDqXURr):

```
    d := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(st))
    var m map[string]interface{}
    err = d.Decode(&m)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `urldecode` and result like this:

```
{"predicates":[{"key":"name","op":"IS_SUBSTRING","string_value":"123"},{"key":"storage_state","op":"NOT_EQUALS","string_value":"STORAGESTATE_ARCHIVED"}]}
```

You can using 3rd lib or online website to decode it:https://www.urldecoder.org/